# More than one module matches. Use the skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module or use the module option to specif

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a new Angular component with a very simple command line: "**ng generate component MY-COMPONENT"**. But the error occurs: "**More than one module matches. Use the skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module or use the module option to specify a module.**"

I'm using version "11.2.19" of angular CLI

Comment: use `--module` to specific which module you want to component to be generated in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this error happen when you have more than one "app.module" in the project.

You can try to solve it by adding the option "--skip-import" to the command, like this:

```
ng generate component MY-COMPONENT  --skip-import
```

**But then you will have to add the "import" manually in the app-module**